# Blazor component get multiple selection

Tags: c#, components, blazor, blazor-webassembly, webassembly

## Description

I´ve created a Blazor wasm application. There I´ve build my own `InputSelect<string>` component which get a string of ids (example: "1,2,3,4,5"). I parse the ids show them and can return then converted back into a string. If the multible select menu has changed I want to update my variable `selectedServergroups` with new values. But I just got the first selected value in the list. How can I get all selected values?

## Source

```
@using PhoenixBot.Shared.Instances.Shared
@using PhoenixBot.Client.Helper
@inherits InputSelect<string>

<select class="@CssClass multi-select" @onchange="OnChange" multiple>
    @if (Servergroups != null)
    {
        @foreach (var group in Servergroups)
        {
            <option value="@Convert.ToInt32(group.Id)" selected="@selectedServergroups.Contains(Convert.ToInt32(group.Id))">@group.Name</option>
        }
    }
</select>

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public List<Servergroup> Servergroups { get; set; }

    private List<int> selectedServergroups { get; set; }

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        base.OnInitialized();

        selectedServergroups = GroupHelper.ParseGroupOfString(CurrentValue);
    }

    private void OnChange(ChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        Serilog.Log.Error(e.Value.ToString());
    }

    protected override bool TryParseValueFromString(string value, out string result, out string validationErrorMessage)
    {
        result = GroupHelper.ConvertGroupOfList(selectedServergroups);
        validationErrorMessage = null;
        return true;
    }
}
```

## Example OnChange Logoutput

```
2020-07-09 08:43:38 [ERR] 75
2020-07-09 08:43:40 [ERR] 74
2020-07-09 08:43:41 [ERR] 73
2020-07-09 08:43:43 [ERR] 73
2020-07-09 08:43:45 [ERR] 73
```

Comment: If someone has the same problem there is currently no official solution. You can read more here on a open github [issue](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/5519). But you can use the workaround in the issue to solve the problem for now.